# Connecting double lines in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a picture of a castle halls with ballrooms:

[image]

This is the code I have so far (just a part of the castle):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{labyrinth/.style = {
        double,
        double distance = 2mm,
        line width = 1mm,
    }}
    \draw[labyrinth] (0,0) --++ (1,0) arc (90:0:1) arc (90:-90:1)
        arc (0:-90:1) --++ (-1,0) arc (-90:-180:1)
        arc (-90:-270:1) arc (180:90:1);
    \draw[labyrinth] (0,0) --++ (0,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I make the lines connect as they do in the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very cheaty way: Just draw over the borders of the circles.

Notes:

- Surely, there's a neat formula to calculate the proper `outer sep`, i.e. the distance the double line needs to protrude into the circle.
- The `double` code is a bit imprecise when it comes to arc which lead to some slivers of black shining through there.

We can solve both by just drawing another white circle over the circle nodes. This is wath the `draw white circle` keys do. They're drawn at the end of the tikzpicture so that there's no arrow anymore that gets drawn afterwards.

---

I'm using the `cd` library/the `tikz-cd` package because it combines a matrix and an easy way to specify connection between nodes.

However, you can also use a

```
\matrix[matrix of nodes] (m) { … };
```

and then just use `(m-<row>-<column>)` to connect the nodes.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  draw white circle/.code=%
    \edef\tikz@temp{\noexpand\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/draw White Circle/.@cmd}%
      {\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}\noexpand\pgfeov}%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter\tikz@atend@picture\expandafter{\tikz@temp}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  white circle radius/.initial=2.5mm,
  white circle color/.initial=white,
  draw White Circle/.code 2 args={%
    \fill[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/white circle color}] (\tikzcdmatrixname-#1-#2.center) 
      circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/white circle radius}];}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  /tikz/labyrinth/.style  ={double, double distance = 2mm, line width = 1mm},
  every cell/.append style={nodes={
    circle, draw, line width=1mm, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=6mm,
    outer sep=+-.707\pgflinewidth, draw white circle}},
  column sep=5mm, row sep=5mm, arrows={labyrinth,-},
  arc rd/.style={rd, out=  0, in= 90}, arc ld/.style={ld, out=180, in= 90},
  arc dr/.style={dr, out=-90, in=180}, arc ru/.style={ur, out=  0, in=-90},
] 
  & & {} \rar \dar \ar[arc ld]
      & {} \ar[arc rd] \\
  & {} \ar[arc ld]
    & {} \ar[rr] \dar
      & & {} \ar[arc rd] \\
{} \ar[arc dr]
  & & {} \rar 
      & {} \rar
        & {} \rar
          & {} \\
  & {} \ar[uu] \rar \ar[arc dr]
    & {} \uar
      & & {} \uar \ar[arc ru] \\
  & & {} \uar\rar
      & {}\ar[uu] \ar[arc ru]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: picture]

Comment: And there's probably also a neat formula to calculate the angle of the missing arcs in the circle and just leave them out when drawing the circles, say with a custom circle shape. Or we just paint another white circle over the existing nodes hiding all weird `double` artefacts.

Comment: Probably one can also draw the black lines, than draw the circles with black borders, than draw white interior.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Yes, basically drawing the picture twice. First black and thick and then white and thin, reusing the same code just with a few different settings.

Comment: I've posted my code, thanks a lot for your ideas!

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I've updated my solution so that it actually draws a white circle over the nodes again but at the very last moment (at the end of the `tikzpicture`).

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out how to do it, though I doubt the quality of the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{labyrinth/.style = {
            double,
            double distance = 2mm,
            line width = 1mm,
        }}
        \tikzset{labyrinthWhite/.style = {
            double,
            double distance = 2mm,
            line width = 0mm,
            white
        }}
        \newcommand{\tmpCircle}[2]{\filldraw[fill = white, draw = black, line width = 1mm] (#1,#2) circle (3mm);}
        %
        \draw[labyrinth] (0,0) --++ (1,0) arc (90:0:1) arc (90:-90:1) arc (0:-90:1) --++ (-1,0) arc (-90:-180:1)
            arc (-90:-270:1) arc (180:90:1);
        \draw[labyrinth] (0,0) --++ (0,-4);
        \draw[labyrinth] (-1,-1) --++ (0,-2) --++ (1,0);
        \draw[labyrinth] (0,-1) --++ (2,0);
        \draw[labyrinth] (0,-2) --++ (3,0);
        \draw[labyrinth] (1,-2) --++ (0,-2);
        \draw[labyrinth] (2,-2) --++ (0,-1);
        %
        \foreach \y in {0,...,4}{
            \tmpCircle{0}{-\y}
        }
        \tmpCircle{1}{0}
        \tmpCircle{1}{-2}
        \tmpCircle{1}{-4}
        \tmpCircle{2}{-1}
        \tmpCircle{2}{-2}
        \tmpCircle{2}{-3}
        \tmpCircle{-1}{-1}
        \tmpCircle{-1}{-3}
        \tmpCircle{-2}{-2}
        \tmpCircle{3}{-2}
        %
        \draw[labyrinthWhite] (0,0) --++ (1,0) arc (90:0:1) arc (90:-90:1) arc (0:-90:1) --++ (-1,0) arc (-90:-180:1)
            arc (-90:-270:1) arc (180:90:1);
        \draw[labyrinthWhite] (0,0) --++ (0,-4);
        \draw[labyrinthWhite] (-1,-1) --++ (0,-2) --++ (1,0);
        \draw[labyrinthWhite] (0,-1) --++ (2,0);
        \draw[labyrinthWhite] (0,-2) --++ (3,0);
        \draw[labyrinthWhite] (1,-2) --++ (0,-2);
        \draw[labyrinthWhite] (2,-2) --++ (0,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```